# ocotkit unable to get organisation private repo commit

Tags: node.js, git, github, octokit

I am using octokit with node and trying to get single commit detail

but getting 404

generated personal access token, owner etc.

for my private repo it's working but for organization Private repository not working i just got access of owner to org and updated token also

```
const { IncomingWebhook } = require('@slack/client');
const humanizeDuration = require('humanize-duration');
const Octokit = require('@octokit/rest');


const GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

const token = GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN;
const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')({
  auth: `token ${token}`
})

module.exports.getGithubCommit = async (build, octokit) => {
    try {
        console.log("Inside Github function");
        const githubRepo   = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        const githubBranch = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        const commitSha    = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        const githubCommit = await octokit.git.getCommit({
            commit_sha: commitSha,
            owner: 'harshmanvar',
            repo: githubRepo,
        });
        console.log("Github commit value",githubCommit);
        return githubCommit;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error',err);
        return err;
    }
};

const githubCommit = module.exports.getGithubCommit(build, octokit);
```

Let me know if i am missing something and it is due to just got access of organization so I can't access older commit detail?

when i tried to list repository of organisation in all repository i found

```
owner : [object]

{ id: 12345674890,
       node_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       name: 'XXXXX',
       full_name: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
       private: true,
       owner: [Object],
       html_url: 'https://github.com/org/XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       description: null,
       fork: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

To get commit details from the organization repository we have to pass the org name as the owner.

```
commit_sha: commitSha,
            owner: 'acme-org',
            repo: githubRepo,
```